# Facebook Picture zoom animation in swift, picture not showing the initial position

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been trying to make a zoom animation like Facebook when you click a picture into a cell to move into the middle of the screen. The animation works, but for a reason that I can not figure out, it is not starting from the initial position it is giving me another frame. Please help, I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

I am using a collectionView with CustomCell and everything it's done programmatically:

The function in CenterVC:

```
//MARK: Function to animate Image View (it will animate to the middle of the View)
func animateImageView(statusImageView : UIImageView) {
    //Get access to a starting frame
    statusImageView.frame.origin.x = 0
    if let startingFrame = statusImageView.superview?.convert(statusImageView.frame, to: nil) {

        //Add the view from cell to the main view
        let zoomImageView = UIView()
        zoomImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        zoomImageView.frame = statusImageView.frame

        view.addSubview(zoomImageView)


        print("Starting frame is: \(startingFrame)")
        print("Image view frame is: \(statusImageView.frame)")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: { 
            let height = (self.view.frame.width / startingFrame.width) * startingFrame.height
            let y = self.view.frame.height / 2 - (height / 2)

            zoomImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: height)

        })
    }
}
```

This is the pictureView inside the cell  and the constraints (this is where I am setting up the picture for the view, and I am using in cellForRowAtIndexPath cell.centerVC = self):

```
var centerVC : CenterVC?

func animate() {

    centerVC?.animateImageView(statusImageView: pictureView)
}

let pictureView : UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "cat")
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-5-[v0(40)]-5-[v1]-5-[v2(200)]", views: profileImage, postTextView, pictureView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: pictureView)
```

This is what it prints out in the debugger:

```
    Starting frame is: (5.0, 547.5, 365.0, 200.0)
    Image view frame is: (0.0, 195.5, 365.0, 200.0)
```

As you can see the starting frame it's different from the initial frame and position of the picture. The animation it's not leaving the initial position it just appears somewhere on top and animates to the middle. I don't know what to do, please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it was not reading the starting frame rect so I've made a new CGRect that gets the origin and set the size of the picture: (it animates perfectly now)

```
zoomImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: startingFrame.origin, size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: statusImageView.frame.height))
```